# Static Variables on Properties File vs Singleton vs Static Class vs enum

Tags: java

I have lot of static variables that I use in my whole application like:

```
Class A:

final static String a="a";
final static String b="b";
final static String c="c";

Class B:

final static String a="a";
final static String b="b";
final static String e="e";

Class c:

final static String a="a";
final static String c="c";
final static String f="f";
```

I don´t need to change variables at runtime.

So what will be my best opt here?

Comment: Well, do you need these variables set before application startup? Do you need to change any of these variables later to allow some functionality?

Comment: No. They are just variables to incorporate log messages

Comment: An external file only makes sense if you want to change the variables sometimes and don't want to change your program itself. If the variables are always constant you could create a static property class.

Answer (score 0):

You can put these variables in an interface. That way, you will make these "public static final".

Ideally you can even put these into properties file. In that case, these should be config properties of your application which may control a feature or anything that could've been changed from outside(e.g. an url).

Answer (score 0):

Go for a properties file with a singleton `ResourceBundle` instance to read from the same. This will help you manage the variables outside of your core program. This will also help you to re-use the values in some other program as well.